# Parse json to object

Tags: java, json, parsing

I am a newbie in Java, i'm researching how to parse json to object in java.

I have the following Json content:

```
{
"objects": [
    {
        "type": "image",
        "left":0,
        "top":0,
        "width":787,
        "height":1165,
        "src":"image/16_011020002_000_bk.PNG",
        "replaceable":false,
        "lockObject":false
    },
    {
        "type": "image",
        "left":70,
        "top":54,
        "width":669,
        "height":469,
        "src":"image/16_011020002_000_il.PNG",
        "replaceable":false,
        "lockObject":false
    },
    {
        "left":70,
        "top":54,
        "width":669,
        "height":469,
        "direction":"v",
        "fontFamily":"KaitiEG4-Medium-SJIS",
        "fill":"#55626C",
        "text":"旧年中は大変お世話になり\nありがとうございました\n本年も相変わらずご支援のほど\nお願い申し上げます\n\n　　　　　　　平成二十八年　元旦",
        "textAlign":"left",
        "lockObject":false
    },
    {
        "left":70,
        "top":54,
        "width":669,
        "height":469,
        "direction":"v",
        "fontFamily":"LeisuEG4-Medium-SJIS",
        "fill":"#55626C",
        "text":"謹んで\n　初春のお慶びを\n　　　申し上げます",
        "textAlign":"left",
        "lockObject":false
    }
]
}
```

How to design an object for this json and how to parse json to that object?
Help me this issue. Thank you!

Comment: Read about jackson library

Comment: mark  my answer as answered, so if someone will check out this question, will find answer immediatly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope it will help you...!
use Jackson-

```
 JSONArray objects=new JSONObject(jsondata).getJSONArray("objects");  
    for(int i=0;i<objects.length();i++){  
        JSONObject object=objects.getJSONObject(i);  
        System.out.println("value of left=="+object.getString("left"));  
        System.out.println("value of top=="+object.getString("top"));  

    }
```

Comment: I think GSON might be simplier for newbie

Comment: Thank you very much! @vikas balyan

Answer (score 6):

Use some kind of JSON  parser.

GSON

https://github.com/google/gson

or Jackson

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Answer (score 0):

As per your question its seems to be an array representing the json data of type object.

To parse the data we can use the above two parsers mentioned by d__k.

```
I have been using Jackson and we have a ObjectMapper class which converts the data in the specified type. We can use ObjectMapper#readValue to read the data into java object.
```

Kindly find more information at [this](http://java67.blogspot.in/2015/02/how-to-parse-json-tofrom-java-object.html) link.